# Как передать значения из одного метода в другой

Tags: java

Подскажите пожалуйста, как передать значения из одного метода в другой и совершить вычитание? Два метода находятся в одном классе. Не работает вот эта строка (TodoListManager.toDoList.set(getEdit.edit - 1), newBusiness);)

```
public class StartOfTheProgram
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
if(actionOfTheUser == 2)
            {
                System.out.println("Введите номер редактируемого дела");
                System.out.println("Список дел: ");
                for(int numberingOfAffairs = 0; numberingOfAffairs < TodoListManager.toDoList.size(); numberingOfAffairs++)
                {
                    System.out.println((numberingOfAffairs + 1) + " " + TodoListManager.toDoList.get(numberingOfAffairs));
                }
                //принимаем число, номер редактируемого дела
                edit = sc.nextInt();
                System.out.println("Введите новое дело");
                sc.nextLine();
                Edit.getEdit(edit);
                //принимаем описание нового дела
                newBusiness = sc.nextLine();
                Edit.getNewBusiness(newBusiness);
                System.out.println("Изменения внесены в список");
            }
    class Edit{
    public static void getEdit(int edit){
        if((edit - 1) >= 0 && (edit - 1) <= TodoListManager.toDoList.size())
        {
            System.out.println("Вы выбрали дело номер: " + edit);
            for(int numberingOfAffairs = 0; numberingOfAffairs < TodoListManager.toDoList.size(); numberingOfAffairs++)
            {
                if(edit == (numberingOfAffairs + 1))
                {
                    System.out.println((numberingOfAffairs + 1) + " " + TodoListManager.toDoList.get(numberingOfAffairs));
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Вы ввели не корректный номер дела");
            System.out.println(ListOfCases.CHOOSE_ACTION_MESSAGE);
        }
    }

    public static void getNewBusiness(String newBusiness)
    {
        TodoListManager.toDoList.set(getEdit.edit - 1), newBusiness);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public static void getString (String text, int edit)
{
  toDoList.add(edit - 1, text)
}
```

Comment: Мне нужно именно два метода. Потому что из основного класса я передаю с начало значение int edit в нем совершаю действия а потом передаю String text

Comment: @FDmitriyA Нет, не нужно.

Comment: Нужно именно два метода! Значение из метода getEdit  нужно применить в методе getString

Comment: @FDmitriyA Не спорьте. Просто доверьтесь мне - не нужно.

Comment: Я добавил полный код

Comment: @FDmitriyA посмотрите еще раз на код товарища Igor и переосмыслите. Вы реально зря пылите на ровном месте.

Comment: @dmtr посмотрел, попытался сделать так как написано. Не проходит действие связанное с проверкой. В списке Array List, 5 пунктов, если я ввожу цифру 6 то программа не воспринимает проверку if((edit - 1) >= 0 && (edit - 1) <= TodoListManager.toDoList.size()) а продолжает реализацию кода.

Comment: @Igor спасибо за помощь! Подскажите почему теперь не работает проверка if((edit - 1) >= 0 && (edit - 1) <= TodoListManager.toDoList.size()) на правильность введенного числа?

Answer (score -1):

Вызывайте переменную с именем метода с которого её передаете
getEdit.int

Comment: toDoList.set(getEdit(edit) - 1, text); Вот так?

Comment: toDoList.set(getEdit.edit - 1, text)

Comment: так не работает

Comment: Скиньте полный код пожалуйста

Comment: Поменяйте тип метода getEdit на int и добавьте return edit; И вызывайте так: toDoList.set(getEdit() - 1, text);

Comment: Добавил полный код

Comment: Так то же не работает. Требует добавить аргумент в getEdit()

Comment: Добавьте переменную в класс Edit: public int edit; потом в метод getEdit добавьте this.edit=edit;  и в методе getNewBusiness будете вызывать просто переменную toDoList.add(edit -1, text); Но это будет работать только с не статическими методами

Comment: Теперь он ругается на то что я передаю аргумент из не статического метода в статический. Это ошибка. Ругается вот на эту строчку Edit.getEdit(edit); и вот на эту Edit.getNewBusiness(newBusiness);

Comment: Просто поменяйте методы на не статические, разве это критично?

Comment: Я так и сделал. Теперь из main не пересылаются аргументы Edit.getEdit(edit); и Edit.getNewBusiness(newBusiness); Пишет ошибку (Non-static method 'getEdit(int)' cannot be referenced from a static context)

Comment: у меня нету Вашего полного кода,не могу посмотреть в чем проблема.

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответы! Буду думать